# Pandas: What's the difference between df[df[condition]] and df.loc[df[condition]]

Tags: pandas

Using a condition to mask certain rows from a dataframe, I would use:

`df.loc[mask]`

Setting up a mask as a condition (such as selecting only rows having 'y' in column_x) on the dataframe itself without assigning the mask to a variable, I would usually do something like:

`df[df['column_x'] == 'y']`

But it made me wonder what the use of `df.loc` actually is in these cases. Am I getting it wrong or is the use of `loc` in such instances redundant?

Comment: I think you meant `df[df['column_x'] == 'y']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is being smart about you mean by `df[df['column_x'] == 'y']` based on the length of the boolean series `df['column_x'] == 'y'` and the fact that its index happens to align with the index of `df`. It's syntactic sugar. You can imagine cases where a dataframe is nearly square where things would be more ambiguous.

The `.loc` accessor is the official and least ambiguous way to access a subset of a dataframe by rows, columns, or both.